# Syntax error on token "123", invalid VariableDeclaratorId

Tags: java, android

Estou com um erro na classe R.java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendo de java, mas o nome da variável é `123` ? é possível ? já tentou por uma letra no começo pra ver se o erro persiste ?

Comment: não consigo altera a R.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essas variáveis na classe estática e final `drawable` dentro da classe `R` são referências à arquivos de mesmo nome na pasta `res/drawable` do seu projeto. Veja se não tem nenhum arquivo com nome 123 nesta pasta, pois a referência irá falhar já que no Java não se pode ter nome de variável que comece com número.

Comment: Tem uma imagem com o nome 123.png dentro da pasta res/drawable que o F.D.P do cara que me passou o fonte colocou, como eu poderia altera isso? Remover ou altera o nome apenas?

Comment: Se esta imagem está sendo utilizada no seu projeto, é só fazer a refatoração normalmente e caso sobrar algum, alterar no código também. Agora se não utiliza, não vejo o porque deixá-la :). Lembrando que pode ter erro de compilação caso você deletar a imagem e ela esteja sendo referenciada em algum XML ou no código Java.

Comment: Eu fiz uma busca por 123.png é não encontrei nenhuma referência, então eu removi a imagem

Comment: Então tudo certo ;)